# RequestHandlerInterceptor or AccessDecisionVoter which gets invoked first

Tags: spring

I'm using spring boot application. I would like to know RequestHandlerInterceptor or AccessDecisionVoter which gets invoked first

Thanks.

Comment: Any comments on this?

Comment: Anybody have any suggestions ???